# Composite literal uses unkeyed fields

Tags: mongodb, go

I am working with new official mongodb driver for golang. I have created one complex query to insert the data into mongo db and then sort it according to an element value. I am using a filter in which I have created the bson type using :-

```
filter := bson.D{{"autorefid", "100"}}
```

But It is showing a warning saying:

> primitive.E composite literal uses unkeyed fields

The warnings are creating a mess in my code.

Comment: This code looks fine. Maybe the error is on another line?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev there was no error it was a warning which the `go vet` is showing

Comment: Ah right. Thanks for posting a self-answer, learned something today :)

Comment: to disable the warning in vs code, `ctrl+,` search `go.vetflags` add item `-composites=false`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The warnings can be stopped by setting the check flag to false.

```
$ go doc cmd/vet
```

> By default all checks are performed. If any flags are explicitly set to true, only those tests are run. Conversely, if any flag is
>   explicitly set to false, only those tests are disabled. Thus
>   -printf=true runs the printf check, -printf=false runs all checks except the printf check.
>
> ```
> Unkeyed composite literals
>
> Flag: -composites
>
> Composite struct literals that do not use the field-keyed syntax.
> ```

But the warning is due to not providing the keys name when setting the value in `primitive.E` struct.

Setting keys for `primitive.E` struct will remove the warning messages. For example

```
filter := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "autorefid", Value: "100"}}
```

> Package primitive contains types similar to Go primitives for BSON
>   types can do not have direct Go primitive representations.

```
type E struct {
    Key   string
    Value interface{}
}
```

> E represents a BSON element for a D. It is usually used inside a D.

For more information have a look at [primitive.E](https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson/primitive#E)

Comment: I see its cleaner when we provide the keys

Comment: filter := bson.D{{Key: "autorefid", Value: "100"}}     // skipping `primitive.E` also works.

Comment: So if we have it in a variable `e := functionWhichReturnsE(...)` and we need a `bson.D` we need to do `bd := bson.D{Key: e.Key, Value: e.Value}` ? looks ok, until you do it for `template.Template`. Better to disable it smh

Comment: I think I'll add something like 
`func E(s string, i interface{}) bson.E { return bson.E{ Key: s, Value: i, } }` to my `utils` package :S

Answer (score 45):

You can simply change:

```
filter := bson.D{{"autorefid", "100"}}
```

to:

```
filter := bson.D{{Key: "autorefid", Value: "100"}}
```

//Skip primitive.E as said by Chris W

Answer (score 44):

Since no one else has pointed this out — the warning is there to safeguard you from changes in the third-party API breaking your code silently.

Ignoring this `vet` warning has the potential to lead to really nasty and hard to track down runtime bugs, so you'd be better off if you were to **always specify the keys of 3rd party `struct`s explicitly**.

Such would be the case if the maintainers of the library you are using decided to change the order of elements in their `struct` for whatever reason. For example, switching `Key` with `Value`, in the OP case. Your code would still appear to compile just fine, but what you intended to be the key would now be passed as the value and vice versa, and things would just start breaking in unexpected ways.

Comment: This explains why it only warns about struct from other package. This won't warn about struct from the same package of the code.

Comment: Most of the code uses same models package for struct. This should not be a warning, as using the struct literal initialization catches the errors while copying the structs. The newly added fields in the struct will fail at compile time. If we use key value type of initialization, we will not able to catch the missing new fields during copy operations

Comment: strange there's this warning because if you look at mongo's documentation for golang + export code feature of Compass, they do not use Key-Value pair for bson.D.

Answer (score 26):

You can change:

```
filter := bson.D{{"autorefid", "100"}}
```

to:

```
filter := bson.D{primitive.E{Key: "autorefid", Value: "100"}}
```

Answer (score 16):

Actually, if **ordered** representation of a BSON document doesn't necessary you can change your BSON document to **unordered** representation by simply change

```
filter := bson.D{{"autorefid", "100"}}
```

to

```
filter := bson.M{"autorefid": "100"}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64281937/11771377) stackoverflow answer for more details about `bson.D` vs `bson.M`. The MongoDB server is smart enough to find matching indices regardless of the used order.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vscode try disable the following in settings:

[image]