# Is order of array of bson.M maintained in mongodb go driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mongo-go

I'm using Mongodb go driver and still figuring out how to aggregate.
My question is, if I use []bson.M as pipelines as shown by the code below:

```
    collection.Aggregate(
    ctx,
    []bson.M{
        bson.M{
            "$match": filter,
        },
        bson.M{
            "$sort": sort,
        },
    },
)
```

Is it certain that the match is always first before the sort? Should I switch to mongo.Pipeline ([]bson.D) instead for 100% maintained order? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]bson.M` is a slice, and slices do maintain order. `$match` will always be taken first, and `$sort` as second.

`bson.M` is a map, so if you have multiple elements (key-value pairs) in it, order inside it is not maintained.

You may use whichever is more convenient for you (`[]bson.M` or `[]bson.D` or `mongo.Pipeline`).

You must use `bson.D` when order is important inside a single document, e.g. when sorting by multiple fields. For details, see [bson.D vs bson.M for find queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64281675/bson-d-vs-bson-m-for-find-queries/64281937#64281937).