# Golang Mongo $in filter query throwing an error, (BadValue) unknown top level operator: $in

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch the details from the MongoDB where value of a particular attribute is either a or b.
For example,
In my collection Test(Attr_A, Attr_B, Attr_C) get the record where value of Attr_C is either "x" or "y".

Filter Query:

```
filter := bson.M{"Attr_A": "123", "Attr_B": "456",
        "$in": bson.A{bson.D{{"Attr_C", "x"}},
            bson.D{{"Attr_C", "y"}}}}
result := repo.DBPlug.Get("Test", filter)
```

Error I am getting is,

(BadValue) unknown top level operator: $in. If you have a field name that starts with a '$' symbol, consider using $getField or $setField.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the field name for the `$in` operation.
Since the JSON filter query should look like:

```
find({"Attr_A": "123", "Attr_B": "456", "Attr_C": {$in: ["x","y"]}})
```

I guess in BSON it should be something like:

```
filter := bson.M{"Attr_A": "123", "Attr_B": "456",
        "Attr_C": bson.M{"$in": bson.A{"x","y"}}}
```

or something like:

```
filter := bson.M{"Attr_A": "123", "Attr_B": "456",
          bson.D{{"Attr_C", bson.D{{"$in", bson.A{"x","y"}}}}}
          }
```

or:

```
filter := bson.D{{"Attr_A": "123"}, {"Attr_B": "456"},
            {bson.D{{"Attr_C", bson.D{{"$in", bson.A{"x","y"}}}
            }}
          }}
```

Since this is a filter, the use of bson.M or bson.D is according to your choice - there is no difference in this case. See [elaboration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64281675/bson-d-vs-bson-m-for-find-queries)

Answer (score 0):

In pure JSON format your filter query would be:

```
{
    "Attr_A": "123", 
    "Attr_B": "456",
    "Attr_C": {
        "$in": ["x", "y", "z"],
    },
}
```

Simply translating this to bson, you get

```
filter := bson.M{
    "Attr_A": "123", 
    "Attr_B": "456",
    "Attr_C": bson.M{
        "$in": bson.A{"x", "y", "z"},
    },
}
result := repo.DBPlug.Get("Test", filter)
```

Comment: Why is this answer better than the previous one?

Comment: @nimrodserok it is short and simple, well formatted, doesn't include confusing alternations