# struct literal uses unkeyed fields

Tags: go

My goal is to embed function to an existing type.

I am following [Effective Go](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#arrays)

The problem is it warns `var parent *embedding.Parent github.com/kidfrom/learn-golang/embedding.Child struct literal uses unkeyed fields`.

The current solution is to create `NewChild(parent *Parent) *Child`. However, I am afraid that this is just tricking the compiler and in the future it will panic unexpectedly, so what am I doing wrong?

```
func NewChild(parent *Parent) *Child {
    return &Child{parent}
}
```

cmd/test/main.go

```
package main

import "github.com/kidfrom/learn-golang/embedding"

func main() {
    parent := &embedding.Parent{}
    child := &embedding.Child{parent} // it warns `var parent *embedding.Parent
github.com/kidfrom/learn-golang/embedding.Child struct literal uses unkeyed fields`
    child.CallParentMethod()
}
```

embedding.go

```
package embedding

import "fmt"

type Parent struct{}

func (p *Parent) parentMethod() {
    fmt.Println("parent method")
}

type Child struct {
    *Parent
}

func (c *Child) CallParentMethod() {
    c.parentMethod()
}
```

Comment: Good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63747469/2190251

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warning you are getting is most likely from [go-staticcheck](https://staticcheck.io/). You'd also see a similar warning by running:

```
$ go vet

./main.go:8:12: github.com/kidfrom/learn-golang/embedding.Child composite literal uses unkeyed fields
```

Checking the docs of the package you are importing:

```
$ go doc "github.com/kidfrom/learn-golang/embedding" Child

package embedding // import "github.com/kidfrom/learn-golang/embedding"

type Child struct {
        *Parent
}

func NewChild(parent *Parent) *Child
func (c *Child) CallParentMethod()
```

shows the embedded type within `Child` is `Parent`, so to fix the warning explicitly assign the value to this (embedded struct) field:

```
child := &embedding.Child{Parent: parent}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the warning by adding a key to your `*Parent` attribute within the `Child` struct. Example:

```golang
type Child struct {
    Parent *Parent
}
```

and adjust the initialization of your `child` attribute in your main func as followed:

```golang
child := &embedding.Child{Parent: parent}
```